# Would Mars become habitable to life if the sun starts to expand into a red giant?

Tags: mars, the-sun

If the sun expands then the distance between the sun and mars would become shorter. Thus more heat would reach Mars and perhaps the polar icecaps would melt. Could this lead to a thicker atmosphere and more agreeable temperatures for life to exist there?

Comment: Still no magnetosphere, of course. I'm not entirely certain that this is the best SE site for this question, but I don't have any suggestions of better places to go.

Comment: What kind of life?

Comment: microbic life atleast

Comment: Hi @Maurice I think this is best on Astronomy SE.

Comment: @Puffin whats the difference between the two exactly?

Comment: @Maurice  Compare these two lists https://space.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic vs https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic . You might be tempted to think that the 6th bullet on the Space SE list is ok, but its much more helpful for me to say that you won't find that kind of thing discussed here.

Comment: Who says it isn't habitable now?  Underground?  Under ice caps?

Comment: @Maurice One difference is that Space SE deals with things that happen now or in the fairly near future related to *exploration of space*. Another is that stellar evolution over millions of years is purely Astronomy and does not relate to human exploration of space in any way that can be factually addressed. Stellar and solar-system evolution are purely theoretical and these things are done by astronomers, and questions like these are regularly asked and answered in Astronomy SE and not answered here.

Comment: @Maurice  In fact if you search though Astronomy SE I think you'll find this question answered there already.